# Creating arrays in Ruby, rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make some charts on my app, and so I've started using http://www.jqplot.com/index.php

It uses arrays to input the data, so I'm trying to create some arrays of my data in ruby, that I can then print in the javascript.
i.e. `@array_example = [1,2,3,4,5]` wouldn't work when printed, but `@array_example = "[1,2,3,4,5]"` would work.

Anyway, The first my question would be, if I have:

```
<% @chart_posts = Post.where(:user_id => @profile.user.id) %>
```

Whats a good way to use this data to make an array (if I want the id of each post in the array, and a second array with the `created_at`)?

To be a little more clear, the final arrary needs to look like an array when printed.
i.e. it must have `[`'s around it, and `,`'s in between each item.

Comment: Note: Since it looks like your Post model `belongs_to :user` and User model `has_many :posts`, you can instead write `@profile.user.posts` instead of that Post.where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too clear on what your final array should look like, but I think `map` should get you what you need.

```
ids = @chart_posts.map(&:id) 
# => [1,2,3,4]

created_ats = @chart_posts.map(&:created_at) 
# => [timestamp,timestamp,timestamp,timestamp]
```

You could also combine that into a single 2D array with map as well:

```
array = @chart_posts.map {|post| [post.id, post.created_at]} 
# => [[1, timestamp],[2,timestamp]]
```

Comment: To 'look like an array', if you are embedding it directly to javascript, you can use `array.to_json` to make sure all strings are escaped.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `array.inspect` - it seems to aim for human-readable output.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like grose php hackery...

but join what the guys above have said to return a couple of strings:

```
id_array_string = @chart_posts.map(&:id).inspect 
# => "[1,2,3,4]"

timestamp_array_string = @chart_posts.map(&:created_at).inspect

# => "[timestamp,timestamp,timestamp]"
```